# Diffeomorphism between Euclidean space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

How does one show that if $f:U\rightarrow V$ is a diffeomorphism between open sets $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ then $m=n$?

Here is some working:

For $u\in U$ let $v=f(u)\in V$.  The Jacobi matrices $J_f(u):\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and $J_{f^{-1}}(v):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$.  We have $f\circ f^{-1}=\text{id}_V$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=\text{id}_U$.  The chain rule yields $I_n=J_{\text{id}_V}(v)=J_f(u)\circ J_{f^{-1}}(v):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, the identity, and $I_m=J_{\text{id}_U}(u)=J_{f^{-1}}(v)\circ J_f(u):\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, again the identity.

By definition this means that $J_f(u)$ is invertible with inverse $J_{f^{-1}}(v)$, so we must have $m=n$.

Comment: Take the derivative.

Comment: And then don't forget the chain rule.

Comment: Because there exists an invertible map in $\mathscr L(\Bbb R^m;\Bbb R^n)$ only when $m=n$

Comment: Like Vim said, only $n \times n$ matrices( here the Jacobian) may  be invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the map to an open ball $B(x,r)$ within $U$, to get a local diffeomorphism. Then the Jacobian $Jf|_{B(x,r)}$ must be invertible. But the Jacobian
is (represented by) an $n \times m$ matrix.

Comment: Because the Jacobian represents locally the derivative of the map. And a diffeomorphism s a differentiable  map with a differentiable inverse,  where the form of inverse is given by the inverse function theorem.

Comment: There is no need to restrict to a ball. Just consider the Jacobian at a point.

Comment: Yes, of course that would also work.